# Logstatsh help needed to write grok filter

Tags: grok

I am new to this group. Can you please let me know how can I write sample grok filter for below log message ?

1458164618009,971866112000,samplehost.com Memory pid=48653

1)UnixTime
2)Memory used in Kbs
3)Host 
4)Memory Pid is Static text 
5) 48653 is the process ID

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The following grok pattern works for your log sample :

```
%{NUMBER:UNIX_Timestamp},%{NUMBER:memoryUsed},%{GREEDYDATA:host} Memory pid=%{NUMBER:processId}
```

You can use https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ for debugging and creating patterns. And can use https://github.com/hpcugent/logstash-patterns/blob/master/files/grok-patterns for checking what regex might be helpful in your case. Basis the variety of logs you have and are processing, some other patterns might be more useful.